# scanf three times in c doesn`t work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

Hello I have a homework from school to make a program that finds a word and replaces it with another in a text. I havent done char string until now and I have a little problem. I need to scan the Text, the find word and the replace word, but only the text scanf work and the other are just skipping..

```
 char w[10000];
char find[10000];
char replace[10000];
int l,c,b,diff,i,k,yes=0,vm;
printf("Text: ");scanf("%[^\n]s",w);
printf("\nFind: ");scanf("%[^\n]s", find);
printf("\nReplace: ");scanf("%[^\n]s", replace);
```

If you can say why the scanf for find and replace just skips I will be very thankful.

Sorry for bad English not my native language.

Comment: You need to consume the newline character which is in the buffer do it by `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",w);`

Comment: Note that `[^\n]` *is* a conversion specifier, it's not a modifier to the `s` specifier. Also, always check the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: @gopi `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",w)` scans _nothing_ if user enters only a `'\n'`.  `w` remains uninitialized and the `'\n` remains in `stdin` to potential causes similar problem with following `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux I never take the scanf() way to read strings and if OP has already taken that path I said this can be done .. Please take a look at my answer below where I say `fgets()` is good

Comment: @Gopi The answer's suggestion to user `fgets()` is good, Yet the above comment and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28740309/2410359) both suggest using a format that fails to work well when user enters only `'\n'`.  Alternative code for `scanf()` could cope with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
printf("Text: ");scanf("%[^\n]%*c",w);
printf("\nFind: ");scanf("%[^\n]%*c", find);
printf("\nReplace: ");scanf("%[^\n]%*c", replace);
```

Just consume the newline character and get rid of `s` after `[^\n]` which says

> Read till newline character is encountered

---

I would suggest you to use

```
fgets(w,sizeof(w),stdin);
```

which is much safer.

Comment: @BorisMutafov, since this answer helped you, could you consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and also checking your other questions to see if you could accept some of those answers? You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the arrows at the left. Accepting an answer tells the community that the solution works. It also rewards you and the person who answered your question with some reputation. You don't have an obligation to do so, but it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, since scanf should skip leading whitespace, including newlines.

```
char w[10000];
char find[10000];
char replace[10000];
    /* ... */
    printf("Text: ");scanf("%s",w);
    printf("\nFind: ");scanf("%s", find);
    printf("\nReplace: ");scanf("%s", replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]s",w);` has multiple problems:

1. There is no need for `s`.  `"%[^\n]"` is a complete format specifier.  [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind)
2. There is no input limit.  Could use to cope with limits: `char w[10000]; scanf("%9999[^\n]", w);`
3. The format does not consume *anything* is user enters <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  `w` remains uninitialized and `'\n'` remains in `stdin` for the next `scanf()` which does the same thing.

   ```
   // NOT recommended
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", w); This gets stuck on \n only input
   ```
4. Nothing in `scanf("%[^\n]",w);` consumes the typical trailing `'\n'`.  Code could use the following which also checks the `scanf()` result.

   ```
   if (scanf("%9999[^\n]", w) != 1) Handle_EOForEOLonlyInput();
   fgetc(stdin);
   ```

Suggest instead `fgets()`

```
char w[10000];
if (fgets(w, sizeof w, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
// strip possible ending EOL if needed.
w[strcspn(w, "\n")] = 0;
```